# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined i am using angular 4 and trying to store in firebase

Tags: angular

When i am trying to save form data to firebase i am getting this error , i am new to angular & firebase . 
Below is the code .

This is my employee service class

employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database'
import { Employee } from '../../../models/employee.model';
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  employeeList: AngularFireList<any>;
  selectedEmployee: Employee = new Employee();
  constructor(private firebase : AngularFireDatabase ) { }

  getData(){
    this.employeeList = this.firebase.list('employees');
    return this.employeeList;
  } 
  insertEmployee(employee : Employee)
  {
    this.employeeList.push({
      name: employee.name,
      gender: employee.gender,
      email: employee.email,
      phoneNumber: employee.phoneNumber,
      contactPreference: employee.contactPreference,
      dateOfBirth: employee.dateOfBirth,
      department: employee.department,
      isActive: employee.isActive,
      photoPath: employee.photoPath

    });
  }

  updateEmployee(employee : Employee){
    this.employeeList.update(employee.$key,
      {
      name: employee.name,
      gender: employee.gender,
      email: employee.email,
      phoneNumber: employee.phoneNumber,
      contactPreference: employee.contactPreference,
      dateOfBirth: employee.dateOfBirth,
      department: employee.department,
      isActive: employee.isActive,
      photoPath:employee.photoPath
      });
  }

  deleteEmployee($key : string){
    this.employeeList.remove($key);
  }

}
```

console error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAeK9.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because your employeeList is undefined when you try to push, just add this piece of code, that would initialize with your employee values

```
insertEmployee(employee : Employee) 
{
    if(!this.employeeList){
      this.employeeList = this.getData();
    }
      this.employeeList.push({
      name: employee.name,      
      email: employee.email      
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this.firebase.list('employees') return undefined

Try this:

```
     getData(){
        this.employeeList = this.firebase.list('employees') || [];// default arr
        return this.employeeList;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , i tried but getting this error                     [ts]
Type 'AngularFireList<any> | undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any>'.
  Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any>'.
    Property 'query' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.
(property) EmployeeService.employeeList: AngularFireList<any>